Run kamal setup: Exception while executing on host 192.168.0.1: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
I'm newbie in kamal.
It's really a great tool for deployment. Thanks to @dhh .
But I have some difficulties deploying despite having read the documentation.
After configuring the deploy.yml file like this:
# Name of your application. Used to uniquely configure containers.
service: soe

# Name of the container image.
image: noumedem/soe

# Deploy to these servers.
servers:
  web:
    hosts:
      - 51.68.124.156
    labels:
      traefik.http.routers.soe.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.soe.rule: Host(`www.jeteste.site`)
      traefik.http.routers.soe.tls.certresolver: letsencrypt
    options:
      network: 'private'


# Credentials for your image host.
registry:
  # Specify the registry server, if you're not using Docker Hub
  # server: registry.digitalocean.com / ghcr.io / ...
  username: noumedem
  
  # Always use an access token rather than real password when possible.
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

# Inject ENV variables into containers (secrets come from .env).
# Remember to run `kamal env push` after making changes!
env:
  clear:
    RUBY_YJIT_ENABLE: 1
    RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: true
    POSTGRES_USER: "soe_app"
    POSTGRES_DB: "soe_production"
    POSTGRES_HOST: "soe_app-db" # With the pattern: <service_name>-<accessory_name>
  secret:
    - RAILS_MASTER_KEY
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD

# Use a different ssh user than root
ssh:
  user: ubuntu

# Configure builder setup.
#builder:
# args:
#   RUBY_VERSION: 3.3.0
# secrets:
#   - GITHUB_TOKEN
# remote:
#   arch: amd64
#   host: ssh://ubuntu@192.168.0.1

# Use accessory services (secrets come from .env).
accessories:
  db:
    image: postgres:16
    host: 192.168.0.1
    env:
      clear:
        POSTGRES_USER: "soe_app"
        POSTGRES_DB: "soe_production" # The database will be created automatically on first boot.
      secret:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    directories:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    options:
      network: "private"

# Configure custom arguments for Traefik
traefik:
  options:
    publish:
      - "443:443"
    volume:
      - "/letsencrypt/acme.json:/letsencrypt/acme.json" # To save the configuration file.
  args:
    entryPoints.web.address: ":80"
    entryPoints.websecure.address: ":443"
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to: websecure # We want to force https
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme: https
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent: true
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email: "me@example.com"
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage: "/letsencrypt/acme.json" # Must match the path in `volume`
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge: true
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint: web # Must match the role in `servers`

healthcheck:
  interval: 5s
# Configure a custom healthcheck (default is /up on port 3000)
# healthcheck:
#   path: /healthz
#   port: 4000

# Bridge fingerprinted assets, like JS and CSS, between versions to avoid
# hitting 404 on in-flight requests. Combines all files from new and old
# version inside the asset_path.
#
# If your app is using the Sprockets gem, ensure it sets `config.assets.manifest`.
# See https://github.com/basecamp/kamal/issues/626 for details
#
# asset_path: /rails/public/assets

# Configure rolling deploys by setting a wait time between batches of restarts.
# boot:
#   limit: 10 # Can also specify as a percentage of total hosts, such as "25%"
#   wait: 2

# Configure the role used to determine the primary_host. This host takes
# deploy locks, runs health checks during the deploy, and follow logs, etc.
#
# Caution: there's no support for role renaming yet, so be careful to cleanup
#          the previous role on the deployed hosts.
# primary_role: web

# Controls if we abort when see a role with no hosts. Disabling this may be
# useful for more complex deploy configurations.
#
# allow_empty_roles: false

When I run kamal setup , I get this errors:   ERROR (Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout): Exception while executing on host 192.168.0.1: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
kamal setup -> ouput:
  INFO [52cb1c24] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p .kamal on 51.68.124.156
  INFO [52cb1c24] Finished in 0.935 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Acquiring the deploy lock...
Ensure Docker is installed...
  INFO [97718e48] Running docker -v on 51.68.124.156
  INFO [a381a0cc] Running docker -v on 192.168.0.1
  INFO [97718e48] Finished in 0.232 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [718f8a03] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p .kamal on 51.68.124.156
  INFO [718f8a03] Finished in 0.101 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Releasing the deploy lock...
  Finished all in 76.1 seconds
  ERROR (Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout): Exception while executing on host 192.168.0.1: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout

Before running kamal setup in local, I did these steps in my VPS:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install -y docker.io curl git
sudo usermod -a -G docker ubuntu
sudo docker network create --driver bridge private
sudo mkdir -p /letsencrypt && sudo touch /letsencrypt/acme.json && sudo chmod 600 /letsencrypt/acme.json

How can I solve this problem? Please help.

I am not familiar with kamal but 192.168.0.1 is usually your default gateway for your router. Are you sure that is the correct ip address for the database? Did you maybe mean 127.0.0.1 (localhost loopback)?

The error message is saying that your attempt to SSH into 192.168.0.1 is failing.
This is caused by the wrong IP in your host attribute in your postgres accessory
Change host: 192.168.0.1 to host: 51.68.124.156
Think of accessories as separate servers. You must tell Kamal, which server IP it needs to send that docker image to.
